# How to resolve Bad Request on assignments endpoint in classes?

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

When I call the Graph `/assigments` endpoint, I get a Bad Request with the following message:

> Resource not found for the segment 'assignments'.

This same code pattern works with other endpoints like `/teachers` and `/members`, just not `/assignments`.

Code:

```php
$getEventsUrlAssignments = '/education/classes/' . $class->getId() . '/assignments';
try {
    $assignments = $graph->createRequest('GET', $getEventsUrlAssignments)
        ->setReturnType(Model\EducationAssignment::class)
        ->execute();
} 
catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
    dd($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());
}
```

I've added the right permissions as described in the documentation:

- `EduAssignments.ReadBasic`
- `EduAssignments.ReadWriteBasic`
- `EduAssignments.Read`
- `EduAssignments.ReadWrite`

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're receiving this error because  `/assignments` is only available in the Beta version of Graph. If you attempt to call this endpoint using v1.0, Graph will reject the request with the following error:

```php
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'assignments'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "38df490c-3a2b-4fe8-a77e-a7cce82831b5",
            "date": "2020-02-20T18:46:16"
        }
    }
}
```

In order to use the `/assignments` endpoints, you'll need to call the Beta version:

```
/beta/education/assignments/
```

You can tell the SDK to use the Beta version using [`setApiVersion`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/wiki/Example-calls#set-custom-request-data):

```php
$graph = new Graph();
$graph
  ->setBaseUrl("https://graph.microsoft.com/")
  ->setApiVersion("beta")
  ->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

$getEventsUrlAssignments = '/education/classes/' . $class->getId() . '/assignments';
try {
    $assignments = $graph->createRequest('GET', $getEventsUrlAssignments)
        ->setReturnType(Model\EducationAssignment::class)
        ->execute();
} 
catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
    dd($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());
}
```

You'll also need to reference the Beta models since there isn't a model for Assignment in v1.0. This process is described in the SDK's Wiki under [Using Beta Models](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/wiki/Using-Beta-Models).

Comment: Thank you for the edit and the response. Now i get an access denied. Although i enabled the right permissions in portal. Do i need to enable beta as an endpoint as well? Because i don't find the location to do that.

Comment: Scopes are not version dependant. If you're getting Access Denied, I recommend opening a separate question for that. AAD/Oauth is too broad a topic to cover in the comments section. :)